# Can I optimize this ORDER BY before GROUP BY then GROUP BY further, query for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, group-concat

My application is for the use of comparing a product sold by several merchants on a daily basis. A process runs to load the current values of data for each store and enters it into a database along with any previous data. Later I plan to create graphs and such off of the history of data.

```
SELECT `a`.`part_number`, GROUP_CONCAT(`a`.`seller_id` ORDER BY `price` ASC), GROUP_CONCAT(`b`.`part_id` ORDER BY `price` ASC), GROUP_CONCAT(`b`.`price` ORDER BY `price` ASC)
FROM `parts`
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT * 
           FROM (
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM `parts_data` AS `tmp_a`
                 ORDER BY `date_added` DESC
                ) AS `tmp_b`
           GROUP BY `part_id`
          ) AS `b`
ON `a`.`part_id` = `b`.`part_id`
GROUP BY `a`.`part_number`
```

To explain the query a little, I need to select the most recent price information for several *part IDs* and group them together with a selected *part number* for comparison. Also, upon concatenation the grouped items are sorted by price to be highest to lowest.

Each part number also can have any number of item ids associated with it so there is no implication of how many companies are being watched.

```
part_number |  column1  |  column2  |  column3
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            | seller:A1 | seller:A3 | seller:A6
  153231    | id:x423   | id:x534   | id:x902
            | cost:23   | cost:34   | cost:57
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            | seller:A3 | seller:A1 | seller:A6
  345123    | id:x313   | id:x631   | id:x652
            | cost:78   | cost:86   | cost:99
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            | seller:A5 | seller:A1 |
  231756    | id:x663   | id:x291   |
            | cost:35   | cost:52   |
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for bring this to my attention for this exact purpose. I had not known of it.

Comment: [Code Review Question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/7732/9943)